# Random choice inside multiple nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm having some trouble with nested dictionaries.

I want to choose a random state, then a random city from the chosen random state and a neighborhood under the randomly chosen city.

The code was working with only states and cities, but when I added the neighborhoods I started to get key errors. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

```
estados_cidades = {'SP': {'São Paulo': ['Ibirapuera', 'Lapa', 'Mooca'], 'Santos': ['Gonzaga', 'Embaré', 'Aparecida'], 'Araraquara': ['Vila Xavier', 'Centro', 'Gonzaga']}, 'PR': {'Curitiba': ['Xaxim', 'Centro', 'Alto da XV'], 'Londrina': ['Vila Fraternidade', 'Heimtal', 'Parque das Indústrias Leves'], 'Pinhais': ['Vargem Grande', 'Jardim Amélia', 'Atuba']}, 'RJ': {'Rio de Janeiro': ['Tijuca', 'Botafogo', 'Campo Grande'], 'Niterói': ['Baldeador', 'Muriqui', 'Santa Rosa'], 'Duque de Caxias': ['Centro', 'Campo Elíseos', 'Barro Branco']}, 'MG': {'Belo Horizonte': ['Padre Eustáquio', 'Buritis', 'Lindéia'], 'Contagem': ['Água Branca', 'Alvorada', 'Beija-flor'], 'Juiz de Fora': ['São Mateus', 'Centro', 'Boa Vista']}, 'ES': {'Vitória': ['Boa Vista', 'Parque Industrial', 'Jardim da Penha'], 'Serra': ['Barcelona', 'Bela Vista', 'Barro Vermelho'], 'Guarapari'  : ['Muquiçaba', 'Nova Guarapari', 'Meaípe']}, 'RS': {'Porto Alegre': ['Belém Novo', 'Belém Velho', 'Boa Vista do Sul'], 'Canoas': ['Centro', 'Marechal Rondon', 'Nossa Senhora das Graças'], 'São Leopoldo': ['São José', 'Feitoria', 'Rio dos Sinos']}, 'SC': {'Florianópolis': ['Centro', 'Capoeira', 'Trindade'], 'Joinville': ['América', 'Atiradores', 'Bucarein'], 'Blumenau': ['Água Verde', 'Boa Vista', 'Bom Retiro']}, 'MS': {'Campo Grande': ['América', 'Guanandi', 'Centenário'], 'Cuiabá': ['Jardim dos Ipês', 'Jardim Passaredo', 'Lagoa Azul'], 'Dourados': ['Campo Belo', 'Altos do Indaiá', 'Jardim Central']}, 'MT': {'Cuiabá': ['Altos do Coxipó', 'Jardim dos Ipês', 'Jardim Passaredo'], 'Sorriso': ['Bela Vista', 'Califórnia', 'Caravágio'], 'Várzea Grande': ['Água Vermelha', 'Água Limpa', '7 de Maio']}, 'GO': {'Goiânia': ['Setor Central', 'Setor Serrinha', 'Setor Jardim América'], 'Anápolis': ['Alvorada', 'Alto da Bela Vista', 'Anexo Bom Sucesso'], 'Trindade': ['Setor Sul', 'Centro', 'Setor Barcelos']}, 'TO': {'Araguaína': ['Parque Bom Viver', 'Ponte', 'Parque Vale Araguaia'], 'Gurupi': ['Alto da Boa Vista', 'Alto dos Buritis', 'Cidade Industrial'], 'Palmas': ['Jardim Taquari', 'Setor Santa Fé', 'Setor União Sul']}, 'BA': {'Salvador': ['Alto da Terezinha', 'Alto do Cabrito', 'Amaralina'], 'Ilhéus': ['Portal', 'São Francisco', 'Centro'], 'Camaçari': ['Abrantes', 'Alto da Cruz', 'Alto Triângulo']}, 'SE': {'Lagarto': ['Cidade Nova', 'Centro', 'Novo Horizonte'], 'Arapiraca': ['Guaribas', 'Eldorados', 'Alto Cruziero'], 'Aracaju': ['Getúlio Vargas', 'Peneira Lobo', 'Centro']}, 'PE': {'Caruaru': ['Caiuca', 'Centenário', 'Centro'], 'Recife': ['Água Fria', 'Centro', 'Arruda'], 'Petrolina': ['Jardim Amazonas', 'Cacheado', 'Terras do Sul']}, 'AL': {'Arapiraca': ['Alto Cruzeiro', 'Centro', 'Bom Sucesso'], 'Maceió': ['Antares', 'Centro', 'Canaã'], 'Penedo': ['Centro', 'Nosso Senhor', 'Santa Cecília']}, 'PB': {'Campina Grande': ['Cruzeiro', 'Três Irmãs', 'Centro'], 'Patos': ['Distrito Industrial', 'Jardim Magnólia', 'Centro'], 'Tavares': ['Boa Esperança', 'Padre Pio', 'Alvorada']}, 'RN': {'Natal': ['Igapó', 'Guararapes', 'Lagoa Azul'], 'Mossoró': ['Santa Felicidade', 'Campina', 'Bairro Alto'], 'Parnamirim': ['Boqueirão', 'Capão', 'Colombo']}, 'CE': {'Fortaleza': ['Centro', 'Alvorada', 'Bom Retiro'], 'Sobral': ['Lusíadas', 'Centro', 'Sítio Cercado'], 'Brejo Santo': ['Lagoa do Mato', 'Araujao', 'São Francisco']}, 'PI': {'Teresina': ['Centro', 'Guarabira', 'Vale'], 'Parnaíba': ['Alto Campo', 'Capão', 'Centro'], 'Floriano': ['Fazenda Norte', 'Centro', 'Esperança']}, 'MA': {'São Luís': ['Centro', 'Bairro da Luz', 'Bairro Industrial'], 'Açailandia': ['Centro', 'Porta', 'São João'], 'Imperatriz': ['Arcanjo Miguel', 'Centro', 'Avenida']}, 'PA': {'Belém': ['Bairro Central', 'Centro', 'Linha Norte'], 'Santarém': ['Centro', 'Batel', 'Campina'], 'Marabá': ['Mercês', 'Carmo', 'Centro']}, 'AM': {'Manaus': ['Rio Claro', 'Rio Negro', 'Centro'], 'Parintins': ['Centro', 'Avenida', 'Alvorada'], 'Manacapuru': ['Distrito dos Guedes', 'Centro', 'Campo Grande']}, 'RR': {'Boa Vista': ['Centro', 'Morro Dourado', 'Lagoa do Mato'], 'Alto Alegre': ['Zona Rural', 'Paisagem Araripe', 'São Francisco'], 'Rorainópolis': ['Sede', 'Vila Velha', 'Vila Nova']}, 'AC': {'Rio Branco': ['Centro', 'Bairro da Passagem', 'Bairro da Liberdade'], 'Cruzeiro do Sul': ['Centro', 'Centro Histórico', 'Vista Alegre'], 'Sena Madureira': ['Boa Vista', 'Nove de Abril', 'Santa Clara']}, 'AP': {'Macapá': ['Roselândia', 'Centro', 'Capão Raso'], 'Santana': ['Vila Independência', 'Colônia', 'Morro do Castelo'], 'Porto Grande': ['Boa Fortuna', 'Bom Pastor', 'Poço Fundo']}, 'RO': {'Porto Velho': ['São Francisco', 'Centro', 'Alto Limoeiro'], 'Ariquemes': ['Itajara', 'Nossa Senhora da Penha', 'Retiro do Muriaé'], 'Vilhena': ['Centro', 'Mercês', 'Hauer']}}

group_estados = []
for x in range(5):
    estados = random.choice(list(estados_cidades))
    group_estados.append(estados)
    
group_cidades = []
for x in range (5):
    cidade = random.choice(estados_cidades[group_estados[x]])
    group_cidades.append(cidade)

group_bairros = []
for x in range (5):
    bairros = random.choice(estados_cidades[group_cidades[group_bairros[x]]])
    group_bairros.append(bairros)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for any loops.

You want to select a random state:

```
random_state = random.choice(list(estados_cidades)) # 'PB'
```

Then, select a random city:

```
state_info = estados_cidades[random_state]
random_city = random.choice(list(state_info)) # 'Tavares'
```

Then, select a random neighborhood:

```
city_info = state_info[random_city]
random_neighborhood = random.choice(city_info) # 'Padre Pio'
```

---

If you want to do *all of this* multiple times, your loop needs to be around *all of these statements*, so do:

```
group_estados = []
group_cidades = []
group_bairros = []

for _ in range(5):
    random_state = random.choice(list(estados_cidades))

    state_info = estados_cidades[random_state]
    random_city = random.choice(list(state_info))

    city_info = state_info[random_city]
    random_neighborhood = random.choice(city_info)

    group_estados.append(random_state)
    group_cidades.append(random_city)
    group_bairros.append(random_neighborhood)
```

Which gives:

```
# group_estados:
['GO', 'MT', 'MG', 'SP', 'AC']
# group_cidades:
['Goiânia', 'Várzea Grande', 'Juiz de Fora', 'São Paulo', 'Rio Branco']
# group_bairros:
['Setor Central', '7 de Maio', 'Boa Vista', 'Mooca', 'Bairro da Passagem']
```

Comment: I needed a loop because I'm trying to insert multiple times these data into a postgresql database with django.

Thanks a lot for your comment. It helped, I appreaciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, is that you were using `choice` on a dict, so the given indice couldn't be called, you need a list

```
cidade = random.choice(list(estados_cidades[group_estados[x]]))
```

Then `group_bairros` can't be accessed, that is the list you're filling, also you lost the knowledge of the state, you need to keep to be able to get city info

```
bairros = random.choice(estados_cidades[group_cidades[group_bairros[x]]])
```

---

All that, with looping of values instead, it gives

```
group_estados = random.choices(list(estados_cidades), k=5)

group_cidades = []
for state in group_estados:
    cidade = random.choice(list(estados_cidades[state]))
    group_cidades.append((state, cidade))

group_bairros = []
for state, ciudad in group_cidades:
    bairros = random.choice(estados_cidades[state][ciudad])
    group_bairros.append(bairros)
```

Or even

```
group_bairros = [
    choice(estados_cidades[state][choice(list(estados_cidades[state]))])
    for state in choices(list(estados_cidades), k=5)
]
```

Comment: The output came a little bit different than what I wanted but it helped too.

Thanks a lot for your effort in helping me!

Answer (score 0):

you assigned empty list on group_bairros

```
group_bairros = []
for x in range (5):
```

and now you trying to get value by key from this **list**

```
bairros = random.choice(estados_cidades[group_cidades[group_bairros[x]]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. It's helpful as well.

Thanks for asnwering my question!